# Correct global git config for personal access tokens in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to `RUN go get github.com/<user>/<repo>` inside docker. I want to do it with GitHub's [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens). To do that I tried running

```
git config --global url.”https://${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf “https://github.com/"
```

and

```
git config --global url.”https://${GITHUB_USER}:${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf “https://github.com/"
```

both of the commands are throwing similar error

```
error: invalid key: url.”https://<pa_token>@github.com/.insteadOf “https://github.com/
```

Can someone tell me what is the correct way to do it using GitHub PAT?

Comment: not sure if thats a copy paste issue, but the quotes " does not look right

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the issue is with the quotes.

The correct command is

```sh
git config --global url."https://${username}:${access_token}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"
```

Comment: `git config --global url."https://${username}:${access_token}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"` certainly doesn't work. I can't add an answer because this is closed, but the correct command is more like `git remote set-url <remote> https://${username}:${access_token}@github.com/<group>/<repo>;` or so.

Comment: answer worked ```git config --global url."https://USER_NAME:ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/USER_NAME/".insteadOf "https://github.com/USER_NAME/"```